# MYSQL query not working allow to select rows by one of 3 parameters from two tables

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I have two tables

```
id  documenttitle  committee  issuedate
```

and tags

```
documentid  tagname
```

a user is has access to only the documents where they are a member of the relevant committee.  So I want to run a query where I can change the committee, the tag and the document and have the system work out the result.  The query I have is this:

```
SELECT a.`id`,`documenttitle`,`committee`,`issuedate`, `tagname`
FROM `w4c_document_management_documents` AS a 
INNER JOIN `w4c_document_managment_tags` AS b 
ON a.id= b.documentid 
OR tagname = 'tag list' 
OR documenttitle LIKE 'doc%' 
WHERE a.issuedate >= '' 
GROUP BY `documenttitle` HAVING committee = 2 OR committee = 9 OR committee = 10
```

Can only it doesn't seem to limit by tagname.  Any help would be great.

Comment: how could it limit on tag name? You've got a bunch of `OR` in your join clause, meaning that if **ANY** of the individual clauses is true, the whole clause is true, and you'll include the under-consideration records.

Comment: Can you put some sample data in your question and your expected result both in a tabular format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something that look more like this :

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`documenttitle`, a.`committee`, a.`issuedate`, b.`tagname`
FROM `w4c_document_management_documents` AS a 
INNER JOIN `w4c_document_managment_tags` AS b 
ON a.id= b.documentid 
WHERE a.issuedate >= '' 
AND a.committee in (2,9,10)
AND (b.tagname = 'tag list' OR a.documenttitle LIKE 'doc%')
```

OR

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`documenttitle`, a.`committee`, a.`issuedate`, b.`tagname`
FROM `w4c_document_management_documents` AS a 
INNER JOIN `w4c_document_managment_tags` AS b 
ON a.id= b.documentid AND b.tagname = 'tag list'
WHERE a.issuedate >= '' 
AND a.committee in (2,9,10)
AND a.documenttitle LIKE 'doc%'
```

Comment: Fabien TheSolution this is what I was looking for I think.  I don't really know the "in" part and how it works.  How would I adapt this where there are also multiple tags

Comment: `AND a.committee in (2,9,10)` is equal to `AND (a.committee = 2 OR a.committee = 9 OR a.committee = 10)`. So for multiple tags, it can be `AND b.tagname IN ('tag1','tag2','tag3')` instead of `AND b.tagname = 'tag list'`